# is there a way to find all the files which were edited in PyCharm

Tags: python, file

context:
I made some changes to a python file in the PyCharm code editor, a long time ago, but now when I check that same file the file hadn't been changed. the problem was that I had many copies of that file and I don't remember to which of those copies I made changes to,

so it would be helpful if I could see which date, and which python files were edited or opened in PyCharm, although in the home screen of PyCharm there are the previously opened projects but not the specific files

Comment: If you are in windows, you can look at your python files in windows file explorer and check the last modified date.

Comment: In the bottom left there is: Todo, Version Control, Terminal. If you check out Version Control it is most likely that you not only find the changed files, but also what was changed there. Also at the top under: "view" you can see recently changed files.

Comment: Lesson learned? Use a version control system like Git. Don't make copies, make branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bottom left there is:
Todo, Version Control, Terminal. If you check out Version Control it is most likely that you not only find the changed files, but also what was changed there. Also at the top under: "view" you can see recently changed files.